# Ruby: get a list of static methods

Tags: ruby

I have a module `Commands` with several static methods defined (`self.method`).
I want to get a list of methods in `Commands`, but `instance_methods` and similar methods seem to recognize only non-static methods, since the return of `Commands.instance_methods` is empty.

The code is as follows:

```
module Commands
  def self.method_1
  end

  def self.method_N
  end
end
```

`Commands.instance_methods` is empty ( `[]` ).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Commands.singleton_methods` in this case.

It will return array of method names.

Comment: Or `Commands.singleton_methods(false)` or `Commands.methods(false)` depending on what they're after.

Comment: @muistooshort, they can differ?

Answer (score 1):

When you define methods within a module or class definition using this syntax

```
def self.foo
  'foo'
end
```

you are defining a class method, not an instance method.  So calling `Commands.instance_methods` will return empty array unless any have been defined.

To get methods defined on the class but exclude inherited methods, use:

```
Commands.methods(fasle)
```

If you don't pass `false` or `nil` you will get all instance methods including those which have been inherited.

Now if you want to get all 3 types in one shot, you could do something like:

```
[:methods, :instance_methods, :singleton_methods].map{|m| Commands.send(m, false)}
```